# Checking and unchecking do not take place automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, checkbox

In my code Jquery, I used :

```
$('#save').click(function (){
    //Staff...
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
    //Staff...
}
```

In another way, I have:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
   console.log('change ok');
});
```

The problem is that the checking an unchecking only takes place when I check it by mouse, but when i click on `save` button (its code is above), nothing happens.
Any suggestions? thnks

Comment: Have you checked if the click event handler is actually executes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to add `.trigger("change")` after `$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true)` like this :

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true).trigger("change")
```

The [trigger method](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) force to **execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type**.

Note: you forgot a `)` at the end of your first code too. So the code corrected is :

```
$('#save').click(function (){
    //Staff...
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true).trigger("change")
    //Staff...
})
```

You can have a look to this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LpC85/

Answer (score 3):

Changing a property programatically doesn't automatically call the change event, you have to manually invoke it:

```
$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
```

Docs for [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

Comment: This is true, and a common pitfall.

Answer (score 1):

To fire an event automatically you need to use `trigger()` in jQuery

EXAMPLE:`$("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true).trigger('change');`

[**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Answer (score 1):

call the `change` function again.

```
 $('#save').click(function (){
  //Staff...
  $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true).change();
  //Staff...
}); //<---- notice missing closing bracket()
```